# What is the probability the best case occurs? (Comp Sci Type Question)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, computer-science, problem-solving, computational-complexity

I'm having trouble figuring out what's the probability the best case occurs? It's my first time bringing together probabilistic knowledge into computer science. The question goes as such.

Consider this algorithm:

random(X,Y,Z):

```
  print(X)
  if Y != X:
      print(Y)
  if Z != Y and Z != X:
      print(Z)
```

You will suppose the inputs X,Y,Z are chosen at random, uniformly and independently from the set {1,...,k}, (for some k being >=1).

I know that both best and worst case run time of the algo is 1.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the best case?

Comment: 1 is the best case. Big Omega of 1 .

Comment: No, what Chantry Cargill means is: what constitutes the best case? What makes it best?

Comment: Least lines of code being executed? What I meant by best case was the best case running time.

Answer (score 0):

Define the best case senario.

I suspect the best case is just the one print call and just two compares.  That the least number of function calls.

If that is so then you want to find: the probability of choosing the same value three times from a set of $k$.  For every value of Y there is $1/k$ chance that X is the same value.  Likewise for values of $Z$.  Since they are independent; just multiply.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y=X\cap Y=Z) & = \sum_{y=1}^k \mathsf P(Y=y)\mathsf P(X=y)\mathsf P(Z=y) \\[1ex] & = \frac 1 {k^2} \end{align}$$

If we have mutually independent discretely uniform random variables; $X,Y,Z \sim {\cal U}\{1,.. k\}$

---

Now the worst case scenario would be the other extreme.  $X\neq Y$, $Z\neq Y$, and $Z\neq X$; thus ensuring all three print calls are made.

There are ${k \choose 3}3!$ ways to select 3 distinct values for X,Y,Z from a set of $k$, each having probability of $1/k^3$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y\neq X, Y\neq Z, Z\neq X)
& = \sum_{y=1}^k \mathsf P(Y=y) \sum_{\substack{x=1\\:x\neq y}}^k \mathsf P(X=x\cap X\neq Y)\mathsf P(Z\neq x\cap Z\neq y)
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac {(k-1)(k-2)}{k^2}
\\[1ex]
& = {k\choose 3}\frac {3!}{k^3}
 \end{align}$$

Comment: How did you go about solving it like that?

Comment: or thinking about it like that?

Comment: Because I want to apply this method of solving this for lets say the worst case running time in which all lines of code would execute. To make sure I understand it clearly. Thanks

Comment: If $Y=X$ you don't print(Y), if $Z=X$ you don't print(Z).  For every $Y$ value there is a $1/k$ chance that $X$ will have the same value; (there are $k$ values each having the same probability).  Likewise there is a $1/k$ chance $Z=Y$.  Since they are independent, you just multiply.

Comment: Why is there a 1/k chance that X will have the same value?

Comment: Ahh i get it! If i wanted to know the expected value of the number of print statements executed by this algo,I would say it is (k choose 3)3!/k^3. Also, going back to the worst case the probability would just be each 1/k^3 because each has the same probability.